# How to clean VS Code bad function definition link list

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode 1.8.1.
If I remove some file from my workspace, the function definition list is still exist.
How to clean and rebuild the definition links?

[Bad Definition Link of Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPZhc.png)

Comment: i'd check the .vscode directory created at the project's root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the cache of vscode:

*/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage*

Remove the cache then you can rebuild your workspace function reference.